# Javascript replace() function

Tags: javascript, replace

This is a simple replace() question - and I can't get it working to replace a substring in the function below.

```
function linkOnClick(){
    var anyNameYouLike = 'some sort of text/string right here';
    anyNameYouLike.replace('right','in');
    alert(anyNameYouLike)
}
```

It should return "some sort of text/string in here" but doesn't. What am I doing wrong?  I'm fairly new with Javascript (if it isn't obvious...)

Comment: Please make sure you're using the correct tags. The code isn't in Java.

Comment: it IS returning a String but you are not saving it... look at ivanovic's answer

Comment: I recommend looking this kind of thing up on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Just google `javascript mdn <feature>`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
anyNameYouLike = anyNameYouLike.replace('right','in');
```

Comment: Funny how long something as simple as this can take to figure out. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Javascript `replace` handles only first occurrence without global flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript.

Answer (score 9):

In javascript, strings are immutable (they are never modified).  As such, the `.replace()` function does not modify the string you call it on.  Instead, it returns a new string.  So, if you want `anyNameYouLike` to contain the modified string, you have to assign the result to it like this:

```
anyNameYouLike = anyNameYouLike.replace('right','in');
```

For more info, refer to the [MDN description of the `.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) which says this:

> Returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by
>   a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the
>   replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

And, in the description of the `.replace()` method, it says this:

> This method does not change the String object it is called on. It
>   simply returns a new string.